# How to upload and deploy zip file to AWS elastic beanstalk via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I do not want to use the console. No manual processes. I need a command line version, something that I can code in my continuous deployment scripts.

As part of the build process, I can output a ZIP file (be it on my local machine or in CI process, e.g: via bitbucket pipelines or AWS codedeploy VM instance).

I want a command like:

`aws eb deploy my-app ./server.zip`

That is, first upload my chosen zip file and then deploy it (doesn't have to be one command).

The official `eb deploy` does not seem to support this, nor have I been able to find any other method to do this.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Comment: curious why you don't want to manage the entire lifecycle through EB cli as part of `eb deploy` :) .. can you please elaborate your requirements ? (As far as I know, app versions can be uploaded manually only via console)

Comment: I have a custom artefact generation process, bundling multiple JARs from several sub modules into one which eb deploy does not support

Comment: ok, and placing the dependent jars as part of the code repository won't work here ? This is something which then goes in the CI/CD scripts before you run `eb deploy`. You might want to check `.ebignore` file to make sure that the CLI does not ignore the additional jars. 

Later in the deployment process, you can then use the lifecycle hooks provided by Beanstalk like `commands:` and `container_commands:` (depending on a docker/non-docker based environment) to do custom-magic before the application comes up

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think `eb` CLI supports uploading a ZIP and updating an environment but you can use a combination of AWS CLI commands.

1. Upload the ZIP to S3
2. Create an application version
3. Update the environment

Example,

```
aws s3 cp deploy.zip s3://mybucket/deploy.zip
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name my-app --version-label 12345 --source-bundle S3Bucket="mybucket",S3Key="deploy.zip"
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name my-app --environment-name MyApp-env --version-label 12345
```

Comment: That did it for me. Struggled before with the EB-CLI to define a archive file.

Comment: nice, but how to do it without a public s3 bucket?  public bucket with source IP is a problem.

Comment: @bjm88 The S3 bucket does not need to be public. Just ensure that the right access/permissions are set up. For example, the IAM user/role doing the `cp` command must have the `s3:PutObject` permission for the `mybucket` resource.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for this answer as well. I was able to find some AWS documentation that lets you use the Elastic Beanstalk CLI configuration to upload the zip.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact

> ###### Deploying an artifact instead of the project folder
>
> You can tell the EB CLI to deploy a ZIP file or WAR file that you generate as part of a separate build process by adding the following lines to `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` in your project folder.
>
> ```
> deploy:
>  artifact: path/to/buildartifact.zip
> ```
>
> If you configure the EB CLI in your Git repository, and you don't > commit the artifact to source, use the `--staged` option to deploy the latest build.
>
> ```
> ~/eb$ eb deploy --staged
> ```

I tested and it did work for me!

Comment: Also worth nothing that `eb init` generates the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file.

Comment: likely want to include `-l version_label` too!