# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy: skip .ebextensions if no changes to the config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the Docker platform in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. As part of the environment creation, I install a number of dependencies to the instance with `.ebextensions/my.config`

```
commands:
    01_install_make:
        command: |
            sudo yum install -y gcc make
    02_install_headers:
        command: |
            sudo yum install -y kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
    03_install_kernel_extras:
        command: |
            sudo dnf install -y kernel-modules-extra
    04_download_grid_drivers:
        command: |
            aws s3 cp --recursive s3://ec2-linux-nvidia-drivers/latest/ .
    05_add_permissions:
        command: |
            chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run
    06_install_nvidia_driver:
        command: |
            sudo /bin/sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run -s
    (...)
```

These steps are necessary only on environment creation, and it's unlikely I am going to modify them in a daily deployment scenario.

When I run `eb deploy`, everything gets redeployed, `my.config` included. Not only it's not necessary (I haven't touched the config), but it also fails since e.g. Nvidia driver is already installed. What is the canonical way to handle this in EB? Should every command be accompanied by a respective check if the step has been already executed, e.g. driver is loaded already?

Here's how the deployment steps look like according to the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). What I want is to skip the "Initial steps" and run only "deploy" (3) or "configure" and "deploy" (2 & 3).

[image: eb deployment]

Comment: Have you looked at platform hooks? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html , the hooks run AFTER `commands` I mentioned, and both are in the "initial steps" stage (see the figure in the linked doc). Are you certain those won't be also executed with `eb deploy`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple if else statement to detect if the files are installed or not. You just need to find out the file path and check the existance:

```
commands:
  01_install_make:
    command: |
      IS_EXIST=/etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-nodistro.repo
      if [ ! -f "${IS_EXIST}" ]; then
        installation code here..
      fi
```

Files in the .ebextensions folder always will be triggered in every deployment. Disabling a file is not posible unless it is deleted.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I noted in the question that `eb deploy` does that and asked if checking for "evidence" of respective step is the way to go. There seems to be also another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139095/how-to-upload-and-deploy-zip-file-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-via-cli but it produces more work than it saves. 

Your answer doesn't check for presence of `make` nor handles rest of the steps, so I can't accept. I will upvote it, but also add my own, with checks for all commands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like checking if the command has already been successfully executed is the way to go. @darkinSyde answer is generic, so for completeness (and solving this particular problem) I am posting also mine:

```
commands:
    01_install_make_and_gcc:
        command: |
            rpm -q gcc || \
            sudo yum install -y gcc
            rpm -q make || \
            sudo yum install -y make
    02_install_headers:
        command: |
            rpm -q kernel-devel-$(uname -r) || \
            sudo yum install -y kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
    03_install_kernel_extras:
        command: |
            rpm -q kernel-modules-extra || \
            sudo dnf install -y kernel-modules-extra
    04_download_grid_drivers:
        command: |
            nvidia-smi || \
            aws s3 cp --recursive s3://ec2-linux-nvidia-drivers/latest/ .
    05_add_permissions:
        command: |
            nvidia-smi || \
            chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run
    06_install_nvidia_driver:
        command: |
            nvidia-smi || \
            sudo /bin/sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run -s
    08_install_nvidia_toolkit_repository:
        command: |
            nvidia-smi || \
            curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/rpm/nvidia-container-toolkit.repo | \
                 sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.repo
            nvidia-smi || \
            sudo yum install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
```

There could be another way with [How to upload and deploy zip file to AWS elastic beanstalk via CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139095/how-to-upload-and-deploy-zip-file-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-via-cli) , but I didn't like the extra steps it required.